# Swagger UI - How to protect swagger UI access with Auth

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard, swagger-2.0

I have integrated swagger bundle for my dropwizard(v2) app. Now I want to protect my app with the Auth means before accessing the swagger UI username and password show be mandatory. I tried a lot but did not get any success so please can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you can add springdoc-openapi-ui dependency after you should create configuration class for swagger ui. I added example codes below.

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${application-description}") String description,
                             @Value("${application-version}") String version) {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    return new OpenAPI()
            .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
            .components(
                    new Components()
                            .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                                    new SecurityScheme()
                                            .name(securitySchemeName)
                                            .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                                            .scheme("bearer")
                                            .bearerFormat("JWT")
                            )
            )
            .info(new Info().title("API")
                    .version(version)
                    .description(description)
                    .license(new License().name("API")));
}
```